# What is the best way to handle equipment slots in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oop, inheritance, game-development

I am developing a game in unity, using c#.

the game involves ships, which are made up of components such as engine/cannons.
these components essentially act as equipment in RPGs, such as weapons, armour or trinkets/accessories.

I have created a class called ShipComponent, which extends into 7 different subclasses for the types of component, e.g. ShipWeapon, ShipEngine, ShipShields

my aim is for each type of ship in the game to have a different number and layout of slots. these slots can have ShipComponents equipped into them, changing the ship's loadout.

this could equate to the different armour slots in a character RPG, there would be a slot which holds the position of the character's head, and stores the helmet you have equipped to it.
in this space game the position is especially important to be stored since the shape of these ships vary more wildy than a human playermodel would.

the issue is, I don't know how I would restrict the equipment for a slot to only a specific subtype, for instance, I would want to create a slot at the back of the ship that can only contain objects of the ShipEngine subclass, or slots at the front of the ship for guns.

I initially tried using generic type parameters, specifying the type of component this way:

```
public class Slot<T> where T : ShipComponent
{
    public T component;
    public Vector3 position;
    
    public Slot(Vector3 _position)
    {
        position = _position;
    }
}
```

creating an instance like so

```
new Slot<ShipEngine>(new Vector3(0,0,0));
```

this would store only `shipEngine` objects as its component

but since the slots are stored in a list on the ship, the object of type `Slot<ShipEngine>` cannot be stored in a `list<Slot<ShipComponent>>`, as even though `ShipEngine` extends from `ShipComponent`, there's no conversion between `Slot<ShipEngine>` and `Slot<ShipComponent>`, therefore this couldn't be used to store `ShipEngine` slots and `ShipWeapon` slots in the same list.

let me know what you think, feel free to ask me any questions or information I haven't provided enough of.

Comment: what do you expect to happen when you do `var slotList = new List<SOMETHING>(); slotList.Add(new Slot<ShipEngine>(Vector3.down)); slotList.Add(new Slot<ShipWeapon>(Vector3.right)); foreach (var slot in slotList) slot.component = new ShipEngine();`? It's unclear if you want the compiler to forbid that or not... The beginning of the post suggests you would want it to be a compiler error but the end suggests that you would want it to be a runtime error of some kind

Comment: yeah i see what you mean, i guess i would use a method for setting the component, which could just return if it's the wrong type for the slot. like i wouldn't want for it to throw an error, but i guess i was planning on using the field type as a kind of flag for the slot.

Comment: I would use an enum. Put the typing in your base class. In the `Reset` method in your derived classes, set the enum field to the specific derived class. Then you can check the enum type of the base class that is set from the derived class to determine if it can or can not go in a slot. If you also want, you can set the indexes of your slots to mirror the enum, so if the index != (int)enum then do not let it get put into that slot.

Comment: so would this involve 
```public class ShipComponent
{
 public enum ComponentType {ShipEngine, ShipWeapon, ShipShield}

 public ComponentType componentType;

}```
then in the subclass constructors:

```public class ShipEngine : ShipComponent
{
 public ShipEngine() : base()
 {
  componentType = ComponentType.ShipEngine;
 }
}```

I'm not sure how I would use the slot index to mirror the enum, as e.g. there may be 2 engine slots, so perhaps I should give Slot a field to compare with the component's enum instead of using the index? so two slots can have the same value

Comment: yikes the code comes out really messy in comments.

Comment: Yea posting code in comments always looks nasty. You can edit your original question and post new code there. I must have missed the part of your question that said item types have multiple slots. If that's the case you do not need to map an index to an enum, but you can specify a specific enum index that needs to match per slot. To verify adding an item to a slot, check if the slots enum type matches the items type. It is dependent on how you implement your equipment slots and inventory.

Comment: yeah i don't believe i mentioned the part about multiple slots for the same component type, my bad. This enum solution is working a charm, with the added benefit that unity knows how to serialise enums, so i can set the ships slots on individual prefabs instead of hardcoding them. thank you so much for helping me out

Comment: No worries. Glad it helped you out. If you have any further questions I would update your original question with the code you are having trouble with.